# It is possible to declare a constant in SQL Server which provides the column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to ask you if is possible to declare a constant in SQL Server which provides the column name ?

means something like this :

```
declare @column varchar(30)
set @column = 'Column1'

SELECT @column FROM Table1
```

I know that above declaration is wrong but maybe is a solution to provide yourself the column name.

I want to show results for `Column1` but if `Column1` is inside '' then will return with `(No column name)` additional column name and the results on all rows will be `Column1`.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dynamic column names in SQL.

To do so, you need to use dynamic SQL. I suggest reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog for a complete view on this issue - the article is long but comprehensive.

The use of dynamic SQL can expose you to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so use with care.

Comment: @MichaelSwan - Do read that article. If you control the column names used (and these are **not** user supplied) you are OK.

Comment: I provide the column name using `SqlCommand.Parameters` in my business layer project. Nobody else will access my database, only business layer

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to make use of dynamic query and that can be exeucte with the sp_execute if you are using slq server

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(1000)
declare @column varchar(30)  
set @column = 'Column1'
SET @SQLString  = 'SELECT ' + @column + ' in Table1 '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Comment: @Oded - yes that should be there , but not able to locate another solution for this.....

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, you can't do that. You need to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dynamic SQL](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).

The code would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @column varchar(75)
SET @column = 'Column1'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @column + ' from Table1'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@column nvarchar(75)', @column = @column
```

For more info on sp_executesql check [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

---

Like @Oded stated, SQL injection is possible with this type of solutions!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @query varchar(100)
set @query = 'select Column1 from table1'
exec (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, the above declaration is incorrect. But you can store the whole query as a dynamic sql and run it using `Exec()`.

For your case it would be:

```
declare @column varchar(30)
set @column = 'Column1'

declare @sqlSelect varchar(500)

set @sqlSelect = 'SELECT ' + @column + ' in Table1'
Exec( @sqlSelect )
```

Comment: The opportunity is only theoretical if the code isn't exposed to the user directly. Whenever I write such queries, they are usually part of a batch job, which are scheduled to be run automatically. The feature is present in the language to address specific use-cases and it works great with those use cases.